# What is the best term

Tags: terminology

In my course work I developed the same game for a few operating systems independently. The game can be played both offline (with a bot) and in multiplayer mode (I have a server for that). Now I write documentation, and I cannot choose a term: it is not an [application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software), nor a [software suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_suite). I would like to call it an *applications set*, but suppose it's incorrect. So, what is the best term?

Comment: What will having a better term do for you? Who is struggling understanding what this is? Are you creating a game engine or some sort of game service for other games to be build upon?

Comment: @JeffO it's my own project, I just need to show the work quality in the university. So, there is nothing dangerous, I just want to better understand the terminology of software products.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for English stack exchange

Comment: Your game itself is definitely an application. Each port of the game is an application, I guess you could say that you have a set of applications, each one for a different operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same program rewritten for different platforms are generally called [ports](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting). I would say that you have written several ports of a single application.

Answer (score 2):

How about a "multi-platform application"?